# Perl Regex beginning of String

Tags: regex, perl, match

Hello I have a text which looks like this:

And lets say I have a Phone number that looks like this:

```
39349562486245
```

and a Entry in a file that looks like this:

```
1002978;ITM;39349;ITALIEN  MOBIL;5;0;414;177
```

Now The beginning of the Number matches with the one down there how can I check if does begin with that number in Perl. So I am this far but it doesent work:

zeile[5] Is the Phone Number.

```
open( DATEIMAIN, "<$dateimainc" ) || die("Datei $dateimainc kann nicht geöffnet werden!");
    my @zeilenMAIN = <DATEIMAIN>;   


    for(my $lineNMAIN = 1; $lineNMAIN < @zeilenMAIN; $lineNMAIN++)
        {
            @zeileMAINC =  split( /;/, $zeilenMAIN[$lineNMAIN] );

            if ($zeile[5] =~ /^$zeileMAINC[2]/)
            {
                $displaynameB = $zeileMAINC[3];
                last;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should supply some input that demonstrates your problem. This code works as it should, so there really is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is that 1) you are not using `warnings`, 2) when you extract the `zeileMAINC` number, it fails so that you are matching the empty string or undef. If you had warnings on, you might get an error such as `Use of uninitialized value $zeileMAINC[2] in regexp compilation...` To debug, use the Data::Dumper module to print your data to see what it is.

Comment: I am using warnings and I also tried printing the value of zeileMAINC it also is no problem.

Comment: Then show some input and code that demonstrates your problem. This code works as it is.

Comment: I added the part how it exactly looks like by me

Comment: You still have not provided code which demonstrates your problem. Assuming `$zeile[5]` contains your phone number, it *should* match, and only match once (because of the `last` statement). What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a hash of string prefixes, then use that:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

#Load the lines of input data into a hash.
my %prefixes = map { chomp; split ';' } <DATA>;

my @numbers = ('39349562486245','123456789');

#Create a single regex like /^(12345|48956|...)/ for efficiency.
my $regex = '^(' . join('|',map{quotemeta} keys %prefixes) . ')';

for my $num (@numbers)
{
    print "$num is $prefixes{$1}\n" if ($num =~ /$regex/);  
}

__DATA__
39349;ITALIEN
12345;FOO
```

Comment: I cant do it like that because I have a very big list which is not formatted the same way like up there I have to check every entry. Do you have a solution for every Entry ?

Comment: @alexj, what do you mean by every entry?

Comment: This is functionally doing the same thing as what your code in your question intends to do.